# How can I get the ImageNet ILSVRC 2012 data used for the classification challenge?

Tags: dataset, image-classification

I would like to see if I can reproduce some of the image net results. However, I could not find the data (the list of URLs) used for training / testing in the ILSVRC 2012 (or later) classification challenges. I only found http://www.image-net.org/download-imageurls.

Where is the data used for the ImageNet ILSVRC 2012 (or later) classification challenge?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the site [academic torrents](http://academictorrents.com/browse.php?search=imagenet). The imagenet data you are looking for is shared there.

Comment: This seems not to include the classification task.